# What type of warship is this (likely WW2)?

Tags: naval

I know it's not much to go on, but can anyone identify the type of vessel in the photo?

Being officers, there is no cap tally for me to try and zoom in on. [image]

Comment: Given the sheer size of the gun, figure its gotta be a cruiser or bigger.

Comment: What's the origin of the picture? Do you have any idea of which country's Navy it would be? These details can help a lot.

Comment: The officers' cuff insignia could be Austro-Hungarian, British, Italian, Japanese or possibly Ottoman.

Comment: The uniforms seem to point to the Royal Navy: The knotted cuff-insignia: https://uniform-reference.net/insignia/rn/rn_ww1_ranks_officer_1.html, and the four rows of buttons, and the caps match too.

Comment: Agree that British uniforms seem most likely - the cap badge and general cut of the uniforms seem to match quite closely, as well as the cuff insignia.

Comment: The amount of pipe smoking going on is also plausible for the Royal Navy.

Comment: @Andrew Apparently all major powers used very similar looking insignia. But the match with these guys https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-royal-navy-officer-ww1-123070123.html is indeed good

Comment: I usually do not see any markings on the turrets in pictures about WWI or WWII era ships. Could this be "something different"? A training ship, a training setup on-shore, a mockup for designing new models, a turret removed from a decomissioned warship...?

Comment: Only battlehips and battlecruisers could have  guns of such caliber.  Most likely a Royal navy battleship.

Comment: Also, and in case my previous comment is wrong, a now deleted (by the author) answer pointed out that only the Germans used E in their designation schemes for turrets. It was pointed that the uniforms look like Royal Navy uniforms and I guess the author answer deleted the answer because of it, but we do know that the Royal Navy took hold of a few German ships after they were interned at Scapa Flow. That would match the festive appearance of the men (posing on top of a captured enemy ship).

Comment: I know we are not supposed to answer in comments, but I do not feel confident enough to write an answer. But following my previous comment, could it be the [*SMS Baden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_Baden)? It was a German battleship, but the British prevented it from being scuttled at Scapa Flow. They used it to research German battleships (and then it would make sense for them to paint the E, since they would be unfamiliar with the German naming schema). Lots of guesses, i know, but it feels the narrative nicely. I hope that it helps someone write a more solid answer.

Comment: My guess, pre World War 1 era rather than 2.  Note the gun house is narrower than the round barbette it is mounted on, which is seen in "Mark BVIII" turrets shown in http://www.dreadnoughtproject.org/models/fittings/BVIII_Turret/ .

Comment: That is **not** a battleship.  I've visited the Iowa in LA and its turrets and 16" guns are huge, far dwarfing these people.  Maybe 8-12" guns?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica is right: 12" not 16".  See http://www.dreadnoughtproject.org/models/ships/HMAS_Australia/renders/aftTurret_20060822.jpg for a rendition of what a 1910-era British-built 12" gun turret looked like.

Comment: @kimchilover interestingly, [this photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HMSDreadnought_gunsLOCBain17494.jpg) of Dreadnought also shows similar "clamps"; I can find similar ones on a photo of Invincible as well, so it could be any of the contemporary classes with a 12" turret

Comment: One other detail - the man on front left has no curl, which strongly suggests this is WWI era. Until October 1918, "non-military" branches (surgeons, paymasters, etc) had [no curl on the stripes](https://uniform-reference.net/insignia/rn/rn_ww1_ranks_officer_2.html); this was changed 1918 (1915 for engineers).

Comment: @Andrew I agree with you about the "clamps", and about it being any of several 12" gun capital ships.  The 13.5" guns on HMS Orion and so on seem to have been in turrets with more rounded surfaces than the one in question.

Comment: @SJuan76 I brought up the turret designation as a sign of German origin but I probably was in error: One does not need to paint the turret designation as it is already well defined and obvious from its position. It is useful when spoken "Turret Q is on fire", but one needs to be very rookie not to know a turret when looking at it. And if you capture an enemy vessel, you can always simply re-letter-it in your head to your preferred scheme

Comment: @SJuan76 Baden had only 4 turrets, Emil would have been the 5th… Simply by looking at the turret numbers Großer Kurfürst class Linienschiffe and up would fit (also, theoretically, a maneuver foto could explain foreign sailors 'on board' — then there are sometimes naval guns placed *on shore*; and we don't have a good explanation for the 'base'-shape?…) I agree that it is probably British in all aspects, but that is only a reasoned speculation with some uncertainties remaining…

Comment: @SJuan76 the Americans use a white letter E to denote certain battle honors granted to a ship. But those are usually painted on the outside of the superstructure, not a gun turret.

Comment: @jwenting intriguingly, it seems that in the early days of the efficiency awards they did get awarded to (and painted on) specific bits of ships, and it explicitly mentions "even a single gun mount" (p 29 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919232203/http://www.navy.mil/ah_online/archpdf/ah195008.pdf).) I don't think this makes it particularly likely to be a US ship, but it's an interesting footnote!

Answer (score 9):

I agree completely that this looks like Royal Navy officers and a Royal Navy battleship. However, I'm going to add something to @[kimchi-lover](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/22536/kimchi-lover)'s excellent answer, and go a little further - I think there is a reasonable possibility we can identify the ship as well as the general type.

First off, dates. This is before the end of World War I; one of the officers, the lieutenant on the lower left, has no "curl" on his sleeve, and these became [universal in late 1918](https://uniform-reference.net/insignia/rn/rn_ww1_ranks_officer_2.html). He is presumably an engineer, surgeon, or similar. In addition, one of the men is wearing some kind of decoration, but none of the others are. This suggests it was before the end of the war, when service ribbons would have been issued.

Secondly, the ship. @kimchi-lover suggested *Dreadnought*, which [mounted 12" guns](http://www.navweaps.com/Weapons/WNBR_12-45_mk10.php) in similar turrets. I agree with their reasoning, but think this is a slightly earlier vessel. The [four classes](http://www.navweaps.com/Weapons/WNBR_12-40_mk9.php) produced before *Dreadnought* had a similar but slightly different turret, seen here on *Formidable*.

[image]

Compared to *Dreadnought* (below) you can see that the older style turret had a wider "pedestal" and the sides were more steeply sloped back.

[image]

In this image of *Russell*, another pre-dreadnought with the older style turret, you can see the viewing port at the top of the turret and the turret "clamps" at the base.

[image]

The turret these men are sitting on seems to have quite a steep slope, and the same wide pedestal - note that there's space between the right-hand man and the turret edge. The pedestal edge slopes gently downwards, and they can sit comfortably on it, whereas it doesn't look like this would be as easy with the *Dreadnought* style turret where the pedestal is a bit narrower. (The clamps are also exactly the same as seen on *Russell*, though that might be quite a trivial detail.)

This suggests it was [one of four classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_Whitworth_12-inch_40-calibre_naval_gun): *Formidable*, *London*, *Duncan*, or *King Edward VII*. All of them had very similar turret designs. Given these very close similarities, I do not think it is likely to be a ship not built by a British yard. The same guns were also sold abroad for use on Italian and Japanese warships, and seem to have had broadly similar turrets, but it seems unlikely that a visiting RN party would be posed like this on one of them, singing(?) and wearing gloves, wellington boots, etc.

So, can we narrow it down any further? I think we can. The painted letter "E" is the clue; [this book (p. 285)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KkWuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA285#v=onepage&q&f=false) notes that in 1914-15, some of the *King Edward VII* class were painted with recognition letters on the turret sides. HMS *King Edward VII* was "KE".

This is unusual - it's the only case I've found of identification letters actually being painted on turrets, although it does sound like a reasonable approach in large squadrons of identical ships. Apparently the more common approach was to paint distinctive stripes on the funnels - perhaps this was an experiment?

Either way, the "E" here is in more or less exactly where you'd expect to see it if it were "KE". These turrets had a single long flat face towards the back (see below) and it would be the natural place to paint the letters. The "K" is presumably just out of shot.

[image]

Finally, the barrier immediately in front of the guns - a steel sheet with punched holes of varying sizes - is very similar to the one seen in [this photo](https://www.battleships-cruisers.co.uk/ship_photo.php?ProdID=114386) of *King Edward VII*. It's a very small image and the turret itself is concealed, but the resemblance is clear. The same site has a [photo of the officers](https://www.battleships-cruisers.co.uk/ship_photo.php?ProdID=114389), but tragically not clear enough to make out any resemblances...

**If this identification is correct**, which is a bit of an if, it also narrows it down to a very limited period. The letters were only painted on in 1914-15, and *King Edward VII* hit a mine and [sank in January 1916](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_King_Edward_VII) (remarkably, only one man out of almost 800 died). So we have both an earliest and latest date.

Comment: Agree, that sloped turret was one of the first things that struck me.  Looks like a tank turret, not a ww2 battleship main gun.

Comment: Is the letter E actually painted on the turret? It seems to me that it is on the canvas cover over the turret. That might open up the time window a bit.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer: a British capital ship (that is, battleship or battle cruiser) mounting  12" guns of the sort described [here](http://www.navweaps.com/Weapons/WNBR_12-45_mk10.php), that is, any ["Dreadnought"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreadnought) built before 13.5" guns became popular, that is, built in the period 1906-12. Or possibly, as Andrew comments, some other pre-Dreadnought ship from earlier in the century, but using the same, or very similar turret design.

The features that make me sure have to do with the shape of the turret (illustrated [here](http://dreadnoughtproject.org/models/fittings/BVIII_Turret/)), in particular that it is not as wide as the turn-table it rotates on, and with the flat surfaces of its polyhedral shape.  Andrew, in a comment, points out that the series of clamps at the base of the turret, visible in an [illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Dreadnought_(1906)#/media/File:HMSDreadnought_gunsLOCBain17494.jpg) in the Wikipedia article about HMS Dreadnought, is very much like those seen in the OP's photograph.  (I suppose the clamps are to hold a canvas cover or gasket in place, to use when the guns are not in use, and when one wants to keep water from sloshing into the turret.) The follow-on turrets, for 13.5" guns, seem to me to be too rounded, as seen [here](https://mjwrightnz.wordpress.com/2019/06/01/this-week-in-history-my-great-uncles-navy-mess-fork/).

Another feature in common between the OP's turret and the Dreadnought turret is the presence of "sighting hoods", which look like frog's eyes protruding above the front of the turret. This might distinguish the OP's turret from other 12" turrets of the era.

The [turrets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30.5_cm_SK_L/50_gun#/media/File:SMS_Kaiser_turrets_aft2.jpg) of the near contemporary German ship *SMS Kaiser*, which bore guns of essentially the same calibre are distinctively different.  The general shape (an oblong box or "gun house", sitting on a cylindrical pedestal or "barbette") is forced by the technological constraints.  But the exact proportions are different.  In the OP's photograph the barbette is wider than the gun house, but  on the *Kaiser's* the gun house is almost exactly as wide as its barbette, as is the case with [a later ship's](https://russellphillips.uk/battle-of-the-river-plate/) turret, two decades later.  In other [cases](https://nara.getarchive.net/media/the-forward-16-inch-gun-turrets-on-the-battleship-uss-iowa-bb-61-during-its-d69c98?zoom=true) the gun house is slightly wider than the pedestal.

As a speculation, I offer the guess that the feature of the "BVIII" turrets used by *HMS Dreadnought* that caught my eye, that the pedestal was wider than the gun house, was a transitional form, not followed by battleship turrets designed later.

Comment: After a bit more digging, I think you're right it's a 12" turret, but it might be an earlier ship - there were a number of classes which had similar turrets with Mk IX guns rather than Dreadnought's Mk X. You can see the turret for Formidable [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_pair_of_50_ton_guns_on_HMS_Formidable.jpg), for example, and Russell [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Looking_aft_on_HMS_Russell_at_the_Quebec_Tercentenary_1908_LAC_3361845.jpg). The turrets for these ships seem to have a more pronounced slope, which fits with the shape of the turret behind them.

Comment: Interesting that [this turret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_turret#Turret_identification) has a large "E" on the side of it

Comment: And one more follow-up - [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KkWuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA285) refers to "identification letters painted-up on the sides of 12-inch turrets" for four of the King Edward VII class in ~1914; King Edward VII used "KE". It's not clear if this was the only class that used such letters, but it's the only one mentioned in the book. So this looks quite promising!

Comment: If it was indeed King Edward, this would narrow it down a lot - letters painted on ~1914, sunk January 1916.

Comment: Could spell out the main differentials you use to exclude German uniforms/weapons? (It is pretty grainy and the caps especially are supiscious? Also, to simply declare the 'visible metal' as "British" would be more convincing if compared to other contenders (http://www.navweaps.com/Weapons/WNGER_11-545_skc34.php – notice on that example what you call "clamps" might serve other purposes))

Comment: Royal Navy sleeves had [curls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_curl) for officers.

Comment: @LаngLаngС  The loops on the rank-rings of the cuffs are typical of RN uniforms, and not of Kriegsmarine ones, which looked more like US Navy ones (with a crown or star over the loop-less rings).  The cap badge is like a "warning" traffic sign, as in the RN, not like the oval used by the KM.

Comment: @LаngLаngС German turrets seem to have had a vertical side and then a slope back - see eg the turrets on [Baden](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-R17062,_Linienschiff_%22Baden%22.jpg) - or purely vertical sides - [Ostfriesland](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sms_Ostfriesland_inspektion.jpg). I couldn't easily find an example where the slides were sloped like this.

Comment: @Andrew All well, but uniforms, caps, even cap badges, and turrets look *quite similar* in both navies, German one definitely also 'numbering' their turrets with letters/names (Emil; though my impression is the shirt collars in IN were more often stand-up as well? Also compaer the del A). Therefore, since the Q lacks a visual description, I'd think  such a description would fit *into* this answer and could serve nicely for explaining the 'why this/not that' of the verdict?

Comment: @kimchilover I've added a new answer which builds on yours to speculate a bit about the exact identity of the ship - hope this is OK! It seemed a bit easier than leaving many many comments :-)

Comment: @Andrew  Good!   I'm glad you've been able to search more thoroughly than I.